# cross product versus determinant

Tags: python, numpy, vector, scientific-computing, pyqtgraph

I am trying to determine the surface area of a 3D volume using isosurfaces in Python using pyqtgraph and numpy. The problem is not in the generation of the isosurface but in the calculation of the area from vectors.

If understand correctly, the magnitude of the cross product of 2 vectors (A X B) represents the area of the parrallelogram they define.
Similarly, the determinant of a 3x3 matrix, where the first row is unit vectors determines the area of the parrallelogram of the vectors defined by the other 2 rows.

I am using the code below, but I am getting different answers (though of the same magnitude)

```
np.linalg.norm(n, ord=1)
```

> > 185088.05

```
triarea = (np.abs(np.linalg.det(triedges)))
tot = np.sum(triarea)
```

> > 289059.69600568933
> >     Anyone have any ideas on what is going on here?

The following is the complete Python code I am using.

```
#import tiff file
print("Loading volume...")
img = tifffile.imread(r"C:\Users\Nachiket\Desktop\C1-confocal-series.tif")
print("Done")
print("Generating isosurface...")
verts, faces = pg.isosurface(img, img.max()/5.)
print("Done")


#creating an indexed array of vertices
tris = verts[faces]

#calculate area from normals
n = np.cross( tris[::,1 ] - tris[::,0]  , tris[::,2 ] - tris[::,0] )
narea = np.linalg.norm(n, ord=1)

#calculate determinant using unit vectors

triedges = np.zeros(tris.shape)

triedges[::,0]=([[1,1,1]])  #unit vectors
triedges[::,1]=(tris[::,1] - tris[::,0])
triedges[::,2]=(tris[::,2] - tris[::,0])

triarea = np.abs(np.linalg.det(triedges))
tot = np.sum(np.abs(triarea))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way in which the triedges index values are assigned is causing the problem.

Instead of this

```
triedges[::,0]=([[1,1,1]]) #unit vectors
triedges[::,1]=(tris[::,1] - tris[::,0])
triedges[::,2]=(tris[::,2] - tris[::,0])
```

Write

```
triedges[0, ::]=([[1,1,1]]) #unit vectors
triedges[1, ::]=(tris[1, ::] - tris[0, ::])
triedges[2, ::]=(tris[2, ::] - tris[0, ::])
```

For the determinant to represent the area , the vectors must be defined along the row of the matrix but you're assigning the vector arm to the column of the matrix

Comment: No that's not it.  triedges is a large stack n x 3 x 3 , where n represents the number of triangles and is evaluated along the 0th column. See screenshot : http://imgur.com/V1w34bb